# Tab button becomes disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a C# WPF app where there are some buttons on top to perform functions like table lookup or maintenance here:

```
   <Border Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" >
            <Button Content="Upload File" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding CmdUploadFileCtrl}" Width="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Medicine Price" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding CmdMedicinePriceCtrl}" Width="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="NDC Discounts" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding CmdNDCDiscountCtrl}" Width="100"></Button>
            <Button Content="Facility" Margin="0,0,3,0" Command="{Binding CmdFacilityCtrl}" Width="100"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

---

```
<sdk:DataGrid 
                        Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="dgFacility" 
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItemFacility, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LstFacility, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        AllowDrop="False">
```

When user presses Facility tab it goes there, but when then tried to 'Upload file' that button is become disabled. How can I prevent this disabling?

Comment: What does your XAML look like?  What kind of bindings to do you have?

Comment: Bleep bloop fixed your code formatting.  Please look at the preview before submitting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the buttons are bound to commands, there should be code (somewhere) that is determining when the buttons are enabled/disabled.

Depending on what type of commanding is being used you may have a method named something like CanUploadFileCtrl or CmdUploadFileCtrl_CanExecute which returns true/false.

Comment: <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                            <Button Content="Upload File" Margin="0" Width="70" Height="35" Command="{Binding CmdUploadFile}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableUploadFile, Mode=TwoWay}" ></Button>
                            <Button Content="Export" Margin="2,0,0,0" Width="70" x:Name="btnExport" Click="btnExport_Click"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>

Comment: and here       cmdUploadFile = new DelegateCommand(UploadFile);